# Label encoding of date and create new attribute based on quarter using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a date activation and want to create a new attributes based on the date.
For example

```
Activation date          quarter1    quarter2    quarter3   quarter4
2/3/2020(mm/dd/yyyy).       1            0.           0.        0
11/11/2020                  0            0            0         1
```

Comment: Hello, are you using Pandas?

Comment: Yes i am using pandas

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.get_dummies`:

```
data = {'Activation_date': {0: '2/3/2020', 1: '11/11/2020', 2 : '01/05/2023' , 3: '09/09/2012', 4:'05/08/2019'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = (
    pd.concat([
        df,
        pd.get_dummies(
            pd.to_datetime(df.Activation_date).dt.quarter,
            prefix='quarter')
    ],
    axis=1)
)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
  Activation_date  quarter_1  quarter_2  quarter_3  quarter_4
0        2/3/2020          1          0          0          0
1      11/11/2020          0          0          0          1
2      01/05/2023          1          0          0          0
3      09/09/2012          0          0          1          0
4      05/08/2019          0          1          0          0
```

Comment: Thank you. A noob question, but how to append this to the existing dataframe.

Comment: use `pd.concat` @tim83